# How can I recursively replace file and directory names using Terminal?

Tags: macos, recursion, replace, terminal

Using the Terminal on macOS, I want to recursively replace a word with the name of both a directory and a file name. For instance, I have an angular app and the module name is article, all of the file names, and directory names contain the word article. I've already done a find and replace to replace articles with apples in the code. Now I want to do the same with the file structure so both the file names and the directories share the same convention.

Just for information, I've already tried to use the newest Yeoman generator to create new files, but there seems to be an issue with it. The alternative is to duplicate a directory and rename all of the files, this is quite time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it to work with the following script

```
var=$1
if [ -n "$var" ]; then
    CRUDNAME=$1
    CRUDNAMEUPPERCASE=`echo ${CRUDNAME:0:1} | tr  '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`${CRUDNAME:1}
    FOLDERNAME=$CRUDNAME's'
    # Create new folder
    cp -R modules/articles modules/$FOLDERNAME
    # Do the find/replace in all the files
    find modules/$FOLDERNAME -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e 's/Article/'$CRUDNAMEUPPERCASE'/g'
    find modules/$FOLDERNAME -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e 's/article/'$CRUDNAME'/g'
    # Delete useless files due to sed
    rm modules/$FOLDERNAME/**/*-e
    rm modules/$FOLDERNAME/**/**/*-e
    rm modules/$FOLDERNAME/**/**/**/*-e
    # Rename all the files
    for file in modules/$FOLDERNAME/**/*article* ; do mv $file ${file//article/$CRUDNAME} ; done
    for file in modules/$FOLDERNAME/**/**/*article* ; do mv $file ${file//article/$CRUDNAME} ; done
    for file in modules/$FOLDERNAME/**/**/**/*article* ; do mv $file ${file//article/$CRUDNAME} ; done
else
    echo "Usage: sh rename-module.sh [crud-name]"
fi
```

apparently I'm not the only one to encounter this issue

https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs/issues/79